# Pandas datetime failing when mocking datetime.datetime.now()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mocking

For testing I want to mock `datetime.datetime.now()` to make the test unaffected by time changes. This seems to clash with some pandas functionality:

```
import pytest
import datetime
import pandas as pd

mockdate = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

    
def function_to_test():
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
  
    df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['20000101', '20100101'],
                   'offset': [2, 3]})
    df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'))
    b = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) +  pd.to_timedelta(df['offset'], "d")

    return date, b

def test_function_to_test(mocker):  
    with patch(__name__ + '.datetime') as mock_date:
        mock_date.datetime.now.return_value = mockdate
        date, b = function_to_test()

    assert date == mockdate
    assert any(b)
```

This yields:

```
test.py:19: in function_to_test
    b = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) +  pd.to_timedelta(df['offset'], "d")
/opt/miniconda/envs/AR_env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py:451: in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
/opt/miniconda/envs/AR_env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py:368: in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx:492: in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
    ???
pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx:744: in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

>   ???
E   TypeError: <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'> is not convertible to datetime
```

I am aware that `strptime` might not be ideal for the purpose, but I need it at some other place.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your snippet did not work for me, therefore I had to add the following changes:

- remove the unkown `mocker`-fixture
- replace `patch` by `unittest.mock.patch`
- remove unused `pytest`-import

Then I arrive at the following working snippet:

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd
from unittest.mock import patch

import pandas as pd

mockdate = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)


def function_to_test():
    date = datetime.datetime.now()

    df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["20000101", "20100101"], "offset": [2, 3]})
    df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y%m%d"))
    b = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) + pd.to_timedelta(df["offset"], "d")

    return date, b


def test_function_to_test():
    with patch(__name__ + ".datetime") as mock_date:
        mock_date.datetime.now.return_value = mockdate
        date, b = function_to_test()

    assert date == mockdate
    assert any(b)
```

The issue in your test is that by using `unittest.mock.patch` on the imported datetime-library, you mock the entire object and other parts of your code also depend on its functionality. Luckily, you can specify the `wraps` argument to `unittest.mock.patch`. Citing the [documentation of `unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock):

> wraps: Item for the mock object to wrap. If wraps is not None then calling the Mock will pass the call through to the wrapped object (returning the real result). Attribute access on the mock will return a Mock object that wraps the corresponding attribute of the wrapped object (so attempting to access an attribute that doesn’t exist will raise an AttributeError).
>
> If the mock has an explicit return_value set then calls are not passed to the wrapped object and the return_value is returned instead.

The following snippet works for me:

```
import datetime
from unittest.mock import patch

import pandas as pd

mockdate = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)


def function_to_test():
    date = datetime.datetime.now()

    df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["20000101", "20100101"], "offset": [2, 3]})
    df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y%m%d"))
    b = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) + pd.to_timedelta(df["offset"], "d")

    return date, b


def test_function_to_test():
    with patch(__name__ + ".datetime", wraps=datetime) as mock_date:
        mock_date.datetime.now.return_value = mockdate
        date, b = function_to_test()

    assert date == mockdate
    assert any(b)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, great stuff :-)